# Sending traps through net-snmp

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I want to send notifications through **net-snmp**. I am using the `notification.c` source code as an example. I have registered my function in  `snmp_alarm_register` function with an interval of 30 seconds just like the one in `notification.c`. But when I am using gdb I notice that the function registered is not being called but the one in notification ie send_example_notification is being triggered every 30 seconds.

So can someone please suggest me where am I going wrong?

Comment: The problem has been solved. If you look at the notification.c example a function init_notification() is defined which calls snmp_alarm_register function. Similarly we have to define init_FILENAME() function from where we have to call snmp_alarm_register().